# Can I build a Chrome extension which allows users access to a public file?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that users submit the URL of a website's privacy policy, and the backend(with flask) retrieves and analyzes the text. Now I want to store the analysis results in a public file or database so that the results are updated dynamically, and new users can directly use the results.

Are there any tools or methods that allow chrome extension users to access a public file or database?

Comment: you need a server that implements an API to update and query this file/db. Extensions don't have any special ability to access remote files directly, they have to use the same AJAX as any other JS.

Comment: @Barmar So the extension can use AJAX to send requests to a server and get information back, I understand right?

Comment: Yes. Extensions can do pretty much anything ordinary JS in pages can do, and they also have additional capabilities.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your help! I'll have a try